# Extract variadic template parameter pack and use it in another variadic template in a type traits meta-function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming, type-traits

I want to determine if any variadic class template is the base of another class.  Typically I'd use std::is_base_of, but I don't think my use case fits, and I'm not sure if there's already something in std or boost to handle this.  I want the variadic base class template's parameter pack to come from another variadic class template.  Here's some example code that hopefully explains what I want to do:

Usage:

```
is_variadic_base_of<
   VarClassTemplA
   , ClassDerivedFromA
   , VarClassTemplB //Has param pack I want to use with ClassA
>::value;
```

Guts:

```
//test for variadic base of non-variadic
template <template<typename...> class A, typename B, typename... ArgsC>
struct is_variadic_base_of
: std::is_base_of<A<ArgsC...>, B>
{};
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
template <template<typename...> class A, typename B, typename ArgsC>
struct is_variadic_base_of;

template <template<typename...> class A, typename B, 
          template<typename...> class C, typename ...ArgsC>
struct is_variadic_base_of<A, B, C<ArgsC...>> 
: std::is_base_of<A<ArgsC...>, B>
{};
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Not sure it changes anything, but I did a small edit to `VarTemplClassB<int, int, string>`, now it's just `VarTemplClassB`.

Comment: @Johannes: Boo, some seconds! :(

Comment: Lol, don't know how many permutations I tried and didn't land on this one.  Works perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: @pheedbaq: After some time, you'll just get into that pattern matching that partial specializations offer. :)

Comment: @Xeo ohh, that was really short time difference!

Comment: @litb & Xeo: Either of you have a better title for this post?  I often wonder how many dups of questions like these there are just because it's so hard for me to describe my question.

Answer (score 4):

You're nearly there, but try it with a partial specialization:

```
template<
    template<class...> class A, class B, class C
>
struct is_variadic_base_of;

// partial spec
template<
    template<class...> class A, class B,
    template<class...> class C, class... ArgsC
>
struct is_variadic_base_of< A,B,C<ArgsC...> >
  : std::is_base_of< A<ArgsC...>,B >
{};
```

Comment: Well, I tried several things.  Still don't quite have the hang of how to chop things up with specializations, but I'm gettin there.  SO peeps have been a huge help!

Comment: @pheedbaq: Fighto! ;) But I gotta admit, this partial specialization stuff is a part of TMP I really really like, especially the pattern matching it enables.

Comment: Same here.  I'm always impressed at the things that TMP can do, in spite of any ugly duckling syntax.  Just the fact that these things can be done in the first place, along with everything else the language does... pretty awesome.